# How to get only even numbers from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def only_evens(lst):
    """ (list of list of int) -> list of list of int

    Return a list of the lists in lst that contain only even integers. 

    >>> only_evens([[1, 2, 4], [4, 0, 6], [22, 4, 3], [2]])
    [[4, 0, 6], [2]]
    """

    even_lists = []

    for sublist in lst:
        for i in sublist:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                even_lists.append(i)
    return even_lists
```

I can't do this because it returns everything in one list[]
But how can I return sublist that consists only with even integers?

Comment: What does the original indentation look like for your code?

Comment: Mine would return sth like [[4, 0, 6], [4, 0, 6], [4, 0, 6]] instead of [[4, 0, 6], [2]]

Comment: The number of sublist is fixed in your list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would split it into two functions: one which checks if a list contains only even numbers, and the other one is your main function (I renamed it to `get_even_lists()`), which gets all the even lists from a list of lists:

```
def only_even_elements(l):
    """ (list of int) -> bool

    Return a whether a list contains only even integers.

    >>> only_even_elements([1, 2, 4])  # 1 is not even
    False
    """
    for e in l:
        if e % 2 == 1:
            return False
    return True

def get_even_lists(lst):
    """ (list of list of int) -> list of list of int

    Return a list of the lists in lst that contain only even integers. 

    >>> only_evens([[1, 2, 4], [4, 0, 6], [22, 4, 3], [2]])
    [[4, 0, 6], [2]]
    """
    # return [l for l in lst if only_even_elements(l)]
    even_lists = []
    for sublist in lst:
        if only_even_elements(sublist):
            even_lists.append(sublist)
    return even_lists
```

Although, this *could* be done with [`for`/`else`](http://shahriar.svbtle.com/pythons-else-clause-in-loops):

```
def get_even_lists(lst):
    """ (list of list of int) -> list of list of int

    Return a list of the lists in lst that contain only even integers. 

    >>> only_evens([[1, 2, 4], [4, 0, 6], [22, 4, 3], [2]])
    [[4, 0, 6], [2]]
    """
    even_lists = []
    for sublist in lst:
        for i in sublist:
            if i % 2 == 1:
                break
        else:
            even_lists.append(sublist)
    return even_lists
```

Or as others have suggested, a one-liner:

```
def get_even_lists(lst):
    """ (list of list of int) -> list of list of int

    Return a list of the lists in lst that contain only even integers. 

    >>> only_evens([[1, 2, 4], [4, 0, 6], [22, 4, 3], [2]])
    [[4, 0, 6], [2]]
    """
    return [sublst for sublst in lst if all(i % 2 == 0 for i in sublst)]
```

But let's be honest here: while it's arguable that using two functions might be a bit longer and not as "cool" as the other two solutions, it's reusable, easy to read and understand, and it's maintainable. I'd argue it's much better than any other option out there.

Comment: Thanks. 
Your different solutions help me understand from various approaches. 

The second solution(using for/else), however, looks similar like what I tried to do, but what does "break" do?
Also, by running that it only returns [[4, 0, 6]] without [2] and what went wrong?

Comment: @ChangDaeHyun It seems to return `[[4, 0, 6], [2]]` for me, as it's supposed to. Are you sure you copied it right? And what comes to the `break` keyword, it simply breaks the execution of the current innermost loop (in this case the `for i in sublist:`). The `else:` is executed only when a `break` does not happen. More about it [here](http://shahriar.svbtle.com/pythons-else-clause-in-loops).

Comment: I am sorry, it works now. I guess there must have been mistake when I copied before. And after 'break,' you put "else:" below "for" which produce correct answer. But if I put "else:" below "if" [[4, 0, 6], [4, 0, 6], [4, 0, 6], [22, 4, 3], [22, 4, 3], [2]] happens. What does it mean? Shouldn't [22, 4, 3] be eliminated as 3 % 2 == 1?

Comment: Make sure to study the article I linked. `for: else:` is way different from `if: else:`, and you can't just randomly move the else and expect it to still work. The reason you think `[22, 4, 3]` didn't get eliminated in your example, is because you're adding the list for every element of the list. As you can see, there are three `[4, 0, 6]` lists, but only two `[22, 4, 3]` lists. That's because one of the lists got eliminated when the element was `3`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this using functional programming:

```
def only_evens(lst):
    return filter(lambda ls: all(map(lambda n: not n & 1, ls)), lst)
```

**EDIT**

As per J.F. Sebastian's recommendation, I split this into three functions:

```
is_odd = lambda n: n & 1
all_even = lambda arr: not any(map(is_odd, arr))
only_evens = lambda arr: filter(all_even, arr)
```

`is_odd` one checks if a number is odd using bitwise operations for efficiency. `all_even` checks if a list has all even numbers and returns a boolean. `only_evens` takes a list of list of integers and returns a list of the lists that contain only even integers.

Comment: it might be more readable if you create `def all_even(numbers): return not any(n & 1 for n in numbers)` then you could `def only_even(lists): return filter(all_even, lists)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would think not about what you are keeping, but about what you're removing (all lists containing an odd number).  Something like

```
import copy

list_copy = copy.copy(lists)
def only_evens(list_copy):
    for l in list_copy:
        for i in l:
            if i % 2 != 0:
                list_copy.remove(l)
                break
    return(list_copy)
```

(which emphasizes readability over conciseness, to be sure.)

Comment: This mutates the list that's passed in, which isn't part of the function's contract. If you're going to do this, you should make a copy first.

Comment: Good point, I was running it on a copy but will edit to make that clear.

Comment: The assignment operator `=` doesn't copy an object, but aliases it - `copy` and `lists` will refer to the same object if you do `copy = lists`. You could do `import copy` and then `lists_copy = copy.copy(lists)`

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can divide your problem into small parts.

```
def contains_only_evens(lst):
    return sum([x%2 for x in lst]) == 0

def only_evens(lst):
    for sublist in lst:
        if not contains_only_evens(sublist):
            lst.remove(sublist)
    return lst
```

In this way you can:

- iterate over a list and its sublists
- check if the list contains any odd integer
- keep only sublist with no odds values

Comment: The OP wants to filter out the entire sublist if it contains an odd number, not filter individual odd numbers out of sublists.

Comment: @Ben I probably misunderstood the purpose of this question at the beginning. I guess the reason of your downvote is now fixed.